# How to have in many-to-one relation dictionary table with distinct rows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a problem. I have a relation in Hibernate many-to-one - one city can have a lot of student.

And I have somethink like this:

```
Student s = new Student("Mike", "Tyson");
City c = new City("London");

s.setCity(c);

session.save(c);
session.save(s);
```

And it works great :)

But.. When I want to do that:

```
    Student s = new Student("Mike", "Tyson");
    Student s1 = new Student("Mike", "Wilson");
    City c = new City("London");
    City c1 = new City("London");
    s.setCity(c);
    s1.setCity(c1);
    session.save(c);
    session.save(c1);
    session.save(s);
    session.save(s1);
```

I have two rows in table `Cities` with the same name. A Mike Tyson that I associate with one of them, a Mike Wilson with second of them. How can I eliminate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get two cities with the same name! You've created two cities with the same name and stored both of them! Why do you think there is some magic that unifies the two objects???

What about this:

```
Student s = new Student("Mike", "Tyson");
Student s1 = new Student("Mike", "Wilson");
City c = new City("London");
s.setCity(c);
s1.setCity(c);
session.save(c);
session.save(s);
session.save(s1);
```

Comment: Code that you posted works fine.. Soo.. I can't do that what I write on my first post? What a shame :P

Comment: Imagine how many people would ask questions here if hibernate made one object out of two automagically! Thanks god it works straightforward!

Comment: Ok.. ^^ But when I select row from Cities and set it to Student, it will automatically associate Student with this existing row?

Comment: Yes of course! You can query objects from the data store and assign it to existing or new entities.

Comment: You should have a unique constraint on the city-name to avoid such problems! Then you'll get an exception if you try to insert the same city twice.

Comment: I had this constraint at the beginning.. But when Hibernate threw an Exception it was.. Strange for me :P

Comment: lol. Exceptions are not always bad! Sometimes they tell you that you're doing something wrong! ;)

Comment: I know :) but it wasn't logical to me. But thanks for response :)